# запуск андроид приложения камера из моего приложения

Tags: java, c#, android, unity3d, плагин

По порядку... я пытался использовать вот этот java код что-бы запустить приложение камера(в моем юнити приложении я нажимаю на кнопку и должен запускаться метод LaunchCamera:

```
    public class WhenIWin extends Activity
{ 
    public void LaunchCamera()
   {
       Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
       UnityPlayer.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);      
   }

}
```

во время нажатия на кнопку я не получаю никаких ошибок, но и при этом ничего не происходит...

есть еще один java код(вот ссылка на источник: https://answers.unity.com/questions/780406/androidunity-launching-activity-from-unity-activit.html):

```
  public class StartActivity extends Activity 
 {
    private String TAG = "Plug.StartActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Log.d(TAG,"Activity created");
   }
    public static void Call(Activity activity)
   {      
       // Creating an intent with the current activity and the activity we wish to start
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, StartActivity.class);
       activity.startActivity(myIntent);
   }
 }
```

и я так понял при использовании этого кода нужно отредактировать андроид манифест:

```
 <activity android:name = "com.example.plugin.StartActivity"></activity>
```

вот C# код к этому java коду:

```
 // to get the activity
    var androidJC = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    var jo = androidJC.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    // Accessing the class to call a static method on it
    var jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.example.fboomplug.StartActivity");
    // Calling a Call method to which the current activity is passed
    jc.CallStatic("Call", jo);
```

не понимаю что нужно записать в вот этой строке, что-бы запускалась именно камера:

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, StartActivity.class);
```

если перейти по той ссылке что я скинул выше, то можно заметить что человек с ником RexetStudio утверждает что можно организовать запуск другого андроид приложения из моего юнити приложения не используя плагины... и да, это работает, но как я понял только для приложений установленных из play market... это ведь так? или все же можно используя только C# код запустить камеру? помогите пожалуйста... Заранее спасибо...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37315431

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное, woesss! все проверил - работает! Вы мне очень помогли!=)

Comment: Наконец-то! Раз уж вы взялись за интеграцию с ОС - настоятельно рекомендую почитать учебник по обычной разработке под Андроид на java для понимания того как оно вообще устроено. Java не так сильно отличается от шарпа, чтобы вы не смогли понять примеры кода и научиться применять и переносить их в jni-подобные вызовы из шарпа (доки к `AndroidJavaClass` и `AndroidJavaObject` вам в помощь).

Comment: Да, мне это обязательно нужно сделать! Еще раз Огромное Спасибо! Хорошего дня!=)